# Qt utf8 encoding fails on windows but works good on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, encoding

In project we have a code:

```
return QString("%1\u00B0%2' %3").
    arg(std::abs(data.longitude) / 60).
    arg(std::abs(data.longitude) % 60).
    arg(data.longitude > 0 ? 'E' : 'W');
```

This string object is printed in ***QTableView***'s cell. The problem is that it prints degree sign correctly only on linux machines but on windows it prints square. How to fix it?

Qt 4.8, Windows XP.
Linux (any distribution).

UPD:

We have tried anything but `QString::fromLatin1()` only helped a bit: on windows now it correctly prints degree sign while on linux we have extra symbol:

> Â°

So, for this moment we have a "solution" like this:

```
return QString("%1%2%3' %4").
    arg(std::abs(data.longitude) / 60).
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    arg(QString::fromLatin1("\u00B0")).
#else
    arg("\u00B0").
#endif
    arg(std::abs(data.longitude) % 60).
    arg(data.longitude > 0 ? 'E' : 'W');
```

This is very ugly but it works. I appreciate any other fix.

Comment: Since the string literal is in UTF8, you should be using `fromUtf8`. Why aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

It's more or less a happy coincident that the unicode \u00b0 (16bit on win 32 on unix) represents a valid 0xb0 for latin1. I would deduce the String from its wchar_t representation like

```
return QString::fromWString(L"%1\u00B0%2' %3").
    arg(std::abs(data.longitude) / 60).
    arg(std::abs(data.longitude) % 60).
    arg(data.longitude > 0 ? 'E' : 'W');
```

That should work on both platforms and gives you the freedom to encode chars which do not have an 8bit encoding in latin1.

Comment: It's not a coincidence - Unicode's first 256 code points are a direct mapping from latin1, by design.

Comment: @MarkRansom May be I've expressed it poorly. It may be the design by the Unicode consortium but if I write something like "\u00B0" the compiler interprets it as the utf-8 sequence 0xc2 0xb0 on my platform which still holds the valid 0xb0 latin1 code. If however I do "\u00c0" (A with Grave in both latin1 and unicode) the utf-8 sequence is 0xc3 0x80 and the 0xc0 byte is gone. On other platforms this might end up being JIS,SJIS sequences or something else.